# Can't pass variable with JSON objects to for loop

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I try to write script to loop through object and return those which type is equal to custom data type set in HTML. Yet im unable to pass variable with array of objects to my for loop. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong in this code? I receive:

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

PS. It has to be done in raw JavaScript, no jQuery

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var przepisy;

function findData(data) {
    var kuchnia = data.dataset.type;
    var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    myRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status == 200) {

            przepisy = JSON.parse(myRequest.responseText);
        }
    };

    myRequest.open('GET', 'js/przepisy.json');
    myRequest.send();


    for (i = 0; i < przepisy.length; i++) {
        var results = "";
        var obj = przepisy[i];
        var type = przepisy.type;

        if (type === kuchnia) {

            results += obj.name;

            document.write(results);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like `przepisy` is not being initialized properly. Can you verify?

Comment: You're trying to access the results of an asynchronous operation before it has completed.

Comment: First, include your loop in the success callback function so that there is an object to look at. Second: `przepisy = JSON.parse(myRequest.responseText);` should return an Object, not an array. To find out how many properties are in the object, use `Object.keys(przepisy).length`. Or, if you are really trying to get an array. You need to look into the object at one of its properties where the array you seek is stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are making the call to your for loop before you get the data back, which is why the length is 0. You should just move the for loop into your response:

```
   function findData(data) {
        var kuchnia = data.dataset.type;
        var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

           myRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status == 200) {

                        przepisy = JSON.parse(myRequest.responseText);

                      for(i = 0; i < Object.keys(przepisy).length; i++) {
                           var results = "";
                           var obj = przepisy[i];
                           var type = przepisy.type;

                           if(type === kuchnia) {

                                results += obj.name;

                                 document.write(results);
                      }
                  }
            }
        };

        myRequest.open('GET','js/przepisy.json');
        myRequest.send();



    }
```

Comment: And, don't use `.length` on an object. Use: `Object.keys(przepisy).length`

Comment: Thank you for very swift answer, errors disappear but now document.write do not fire when i run the function. No results at all. What can be reason for this ?

Comment: @ScottMarcus thanks for the suggestion. I updated the answer.

Comment: @Ganga `przepisy` is NOT an array of objects. It is an Object that may contain an array of other objects. Do not try to index the object, go into the property that contains the array and index that.

Comment: Yeah you're right :) i just realize that. anyway i found what was wrong. type should be equal to obj.type not przepisy.type 

Thank you for your help  :)